# How to get image file from azure blob storage in django?

Tags: python, django, azure, django-rest-framework, azure-sql-database

I habe build an app using django rest framework,react and deployed it to azure container service. I can successfully upload image on azure blob storage.but i need to process the image by a AI model to predict a result. I can easily get the image data from local database by 'instance.Image.path'.  But when i connect the database to azure database then i cant get the image file.it throws an error called 'this backend doesn’t support absolute path'.so i changed the image.path to image.name but it always get the image name not the image file.I actually need the image file to process.what is the solution for azure service to get the image file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.Code:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage as storage
image_file =  storage.open(self.image.name).read()
img = np.fromstring(image_file, np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```